# Why can't assign permission for normal user?

Tags: tcpdump

Install tcpdump on my debian10:

```
sudo apt install -y tcpdump
which tcpdump
/usr/bin/tcpdump
groupadd pcap
usermod -a -G pcap $USER
sudo chgrp pcap /usr/bin/tcpdump
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/tcpdump
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

Check the `tcpdump` command:

```
tcpdump -nnSX port 443
bash: /usr/bin/tcpdump: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to “log in” to your new group:

```
newgrp pcap
```

Alternatively, log out and log back in again.